# Set the value in the SELECT map

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to send map to the front end. If i put an atom in the key like in the code below it works fine.

```
defp build_select(queryable, opts_select) do
  if opts_select ==  nil do
    queryable
  else
    Enum.reduce opts_select, queryable, fn ({k, v}, queryable) ->
      a = from q in queryable,
        select: %{Data: field(q, ^(String.to_existing_atom k))}   

    end
  end
end
```

But i want to send the k value instead of Data. How would i do that? K is a string.

I tried converting the value of k into atom and using it but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#map/2) with an interpolated list of fields.

```
select_list = Enum.map(opts_select, fn {k, _v} -> String.to_existing_atom(k) end)

from q in queryable, 
select: map(q, ^select_list)
```

Comment: I have to use it as a key value pair in a map because                           
        field(q, ^(String.to_existing_atom k) wont convert into list

Comment: @hammadahmed can you add the expected return value to your question with example value of `opts_select`?

Comment: In opts_select i have k = "status_id" and v  is empty if the k is status_id: then the result will be "status_id": "value".

Answer (score 1):

The `%{key: value}` syntax works for map *only* for hardcoded atoms as keys. For dynamic values, one [should use the hashrocket syntax](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#maps):

This won’t work:

```
key = :foo
%{key: :bar}
#⇒ %{key: :bar}
```

This would:

```
key = :foo
%{key => :bar}
#⇒ %{foo: :bar} # NOTE :foo as a key
```

So, turning back to your example:

```
- select: %{Data: field(q, ^(String.to_existing_atom k))}

+ key = String.to_existing_atom k
+ select: %{k => field(q, ^k)}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it. Can you suggest how i can pass multiple values in a select like if i have multiple fields **k** that i want to display. because select only take one parameter

Comment: I am not sure I get the question properly, but `select: %{k1 => field(q, ^k1), k2 => field(q, ^k2)}` should do.

Comment: i mean if **k** is a `list [status_id, first_name, ...]` like this. I have multiple fields in k so how can i implement it in the above code to display these fields.

Comment: Like `list |> Enum.zip(Enum.map(list, fn e -> field(q, ^e) end)) |> Enum.into(%{})`?

Comment: Thanks i will try this.

Comment: No this is not working what you suggest because `key = String.to_existing_atom k
+ select: %{k => field(q, ^k)}` wont work inside `from q in queryable`

Comment: Of course, this does work. Let me remind: the question I answered is “I want to send the k value instead of Data. How would I do that?” If you have any additional questions, do not hesitate to ask them as _new questions_.

Comment: In this particular case, you need to define `k` upfront, not inside `from` DSL. I provided an answer, I never was going to write the whole code for you.